# JavaScript is not working when clearly it was written correctly

Tags: javascript, html, compiler-errors

I am making a thing that automatically colors code. So far this is my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Put this into an IFRAME on your website</title>
        <style>
            body{
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: scroll;
                background: #000000;
            }
            #code{
                color: #ffffff;
                display: block;
                width: 100vw;
                padding: 2px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
            }
        </style>
        <noscript>
            <style>
                #code{
                    animation: flash 1s linear infinite;
                }
                @keyframes flash{
                    0%{
                        background: #ff0000;
                        color: #ff0000;
                    }
                }
            </style>
        </noscript>
    </head>
    <body onload="alert('...');">
        <pre id="code">
Insert this page into an IFRAME

?scheme=XXXX&lang=XXXX URL queries:

scheme: The color scheme for the code coloration.
Values: normal

lang: The programming language.
Values: js, html

editable: Whether or not the code can be edited.
Values: true, false

var
        </pre>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("script is running");
            try{
                var schemes: {
                    normal: {
                        js: {
                            background: "#ffffff",
                            base: "#000000",
                            variable: "#3c0029",
                            fn: "#0000ff",
                            string: "#0000ff",
                            number: "#0000ff",
                            boolean: "#006666",
                            parameter: "#ffcc00",
                            system: "#006666",
                            data: "#008800",
                            comments: "#006600",
                            misc: "#224444"
                        }
                    }
                };
                var data = {
                    scheme: "normal",
                    lang: "html"
                };
                var code = document.getElementById("code");
                window.onload = function(){
                    alert(location.search);
                    if(location.search){
                        var s = locations.search.substring(1);
                        var ss = s.split("&");
                        for(var i = 0; i < ss.length; i++){
                            var ssn = ss[i].split("=");
                            uri(ssn[0],ssn[1]);
                            alert(ssn);
                        }
                        alert(s);
                        alert(ss);
                    }
                    setInterval(() => {
                        setColors();
                    },1);
                }
                function uri(name,value){
                    try{
                        if(name == "scheme"){
                            data.scheme = schemes[value];
                        }
                        if(name == "lang"){
                            data.lang = value;
                        }
                        if(name == "editable"){
                            code.contenteditable = value == true;
                        }
                    }catch(err){
                        alert(err);
                    }
                }
                function setColors(){
                    var col = data.scheme[data.lang];
                    document.body.style.background = col.background;
                    code.style.color = col.base;
                    if(data.lang == "js"){
                        code.innerHTML = code.innerHTML.replace("var","<span style='color: " + col.variable + "'>&#86;ar</span>");
                    }
                }
            }catch(err){
                alert(err);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that JavaScript is not working. I tried and tried, but the `alert()` in the script tag will not fire, just the one in the body's event handler. I tested making a function called `l()` which has a random alert in it, and then calling it in the body's onclick attribute but it appears just the script in the event attributes of elements works.

Comment: Have you noticed the syntax error? A `var` declaration requires an `=` for initialization, not a `:`

Comment: was that a minor_flux up?

Comment: Because the Javascript errors on "var schemes: {"  line, at that point, all the rest will not run at all, as your application errors out

Comment: I just tried this code and made the edit to the above noted mistook and then found continual errors being flagged to the console. Also seems like there is considerable amount of code missing that would let this actually run correctly - my interpretation is that the variable `data` will have far more properties and complex values than shown so how is `data.lang == "js"` going to be called here?

Comment: Thank you guys, but I am not closing this just yet. This may or may not be the problem, I'll check...

Comment: Just now, I tested it and it works! Thank you so much guys! Also, @ProfessorAbronsius, Minor_Flux is my brother.

Comment: How do I close questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a syntax error
[image] should be `=` instead of `:`

Comment: Some other guys already pegged this btw.